# Text Area Auto Height in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, textarea

I am Developing an Hybrid app using Cordova. I am facing the problem to make Height of Text Area as 50% which will give my app a uniform look on all devices like Tablet,cell phones etc. I tried to google it and try all stuff but did not find a proper solution. Can some one please help me ?

```
<textarea cols="50%">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>
```

I tried some thing like this

Comment: Can you put some code snippet that you have tried?

Comment: I think there is no way to get the the text area height in percent. you need to try something different for your app.

Answer (score -1):

well you need to set the height, not the width. the `cols` sets the width and the attribute `rows` set the height.

use this code to set the `height` to `50%` of the viewport.

```
<textarea rows="50%">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<textarea rows="50%">
    At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
    </textarea>
```

Comment: well, run the code snippet. It is completely working . Remember, the 50% means 50% of viewport. Try changing it to `10%` or `5%` to see the effect.